# drawRect not called on MKPinAnnotationView subclass

Tags: mapkit, drawrect, mkpinannotationview

I implemented a class that extends MKPinAnnotationView.  I want to draw something below the pin, which I hope to achieve by taking over the drawRect:rect message.  I want to do this by painting something myself first and then chaining to the superclass.

The problem is that this message doesn't event get sent.  I already tried setting the frame size to something not empty or nil (the classic cause) without any effect.  Could the implementation of the MKPinAnnotationView somehow cause the drawRect:rect message to not be sent to subclasses?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
@interface QueryAnnotationView : MKPinAnnotationView {
}
- (id)initWithAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString    *)reuseIdentifier;
@end
```

Implementation :

```
#import "QueryAnnotationView.h"
@implementation QueryAnnotationView
- (id)initWithAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier;
{
    self = [super initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self)
    {
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 65, 100);
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSLog(@"drawing my own stuff..");
    [super drawRect:rect];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

in your `(id)initWithAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier`

add this two lines at the end of if (self) block:

```
self.backgroundColor = any color but clear color (e.g. redColor)
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

This works on my code, but I don't know why.

Also, you can try this:

```
- (void)setAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    [super setAnnotation:annotation];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```